# Is there a reverse of BiConsumer for mapping to multiple values like tuples

Tags: java, tuples, java-stream

I was trying to map a stream of strings to the hash of those strings while keeping the strings in the output as well. I ended up converting the hash to a string so that I could either map to a `String[]` or even join them together as one string. I'd have preferred in a lambda's output could have been both a `String` and a `byte[]` avoiding one conversion. Without defining a specific value object to hold just those two, is there an kind of reciprocal `BiConsumer` i.e. a BiProducer?

```
public static final ArrayList<String> inputs; // ... initialized elsewhere
...
inputs.parallelStream().map(s -> {
  try {
    String h = String.format("%032x",
      new BigIntger(1, MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
                         .digest(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
    String[] r = {s, h};
    return r;
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}).foreach(tuple -> {String input = tuple[0], hash = tuple[1]; ...});
```

You see, if in `foreach` I wanted a `byte[]` of the hash I would have liked to pass what I already had in the `map`, otherwise I'd be converting to and from a string merely to be able to pass it conveniently. Obviously if I made a class just to hold both these types, that'd be the laborious solution; is there not a pre-existing affordance for mapping steps feeding to multiple values downstream?

Comment: Your question is contradicting. A `BiConsumer` *consumes* two items without producing anything. The opposite, the hypothetical `BiSupplier`, would produce two items without consuming anything, which would be inappropriate for a `map` operation which expects a `Function`, which consumes an item and produces an item, so the opposite of `Function` is again `Function`. Anything else would be useless as `map` expects a `Function` argument, so you have to provide a `Function` argument without any discussion…

Comment: Boxing the two values into another object is unavoidable with the current state of the art, but if you are looking for a way to code it more pleasant, you may try [StreamEx](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#mapToEntry-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusion about the `BiConsumer` aside, thanks for suggesting [`StreamEx`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#mapToEntry-java.util.function.Function-) in the comments. It looks like it has a very nice way to write this as:

```
StreamEx.of(inputs).toMap(Functions.identity(),
                          s -> {
                            try {
                              return new BigIntger(1, MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
                                         .digest(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
                             } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                               throw new RuntimeException(e);
                             }).etc...;
```

It turns out, for this case, since I know the input is unique, I could do this similarly with the available [grouping collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-):

```
inputs.stream().collect(
    toConcurrentMap(Functions.identity(),
                    s -> {
                      try {
                        return new BigIntger(1, MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
                                   .digest(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
                       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                         throw new RuntimeException(e);
                       }).etc...;
```